# Assigning a Value in the .sql file from variable

Tags: unix

I have a file done.txt which contains the value as "  34523". I want to replace every "?" occurence in the CreateView.sql file with "34523" and write a output to CreateViewFinal.sql file. But it is not doing intended job,instead it is directly assigning $value
 in the CreateViewFinal.sql file. Any help in this matter will be of great help
Find the script:

sed '14 ! d' result.txt >> done.txt
value=$(> CreateViewFinal.sql
echo "run the runView.sh"

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't specified which tool to use to achieve your goal, here's a solution as an easy Perl one liner:

```
perl -e "while (<>) {s/\\?/34523/g; print;}"
```

As a parameter, give a filename, and redirect the output to somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for valuable sugestion. I am using Cygwin. After that i'll use same code in Unix.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
jon@jontest:~$ echo "34523" > done.txt # write value to file
jon@jontest:~$ val=`cat done.txt`      # read into a variable $val
jon@jontest:~$ #create infile.sql with some sample data
jon@jontest:~$ printf "aaaaa\nbbbbb?\n?ccccc\ndd?ddd\ne?ee?ee\n" > infile.sql
jon@jontest:~$ sed "s/\?/$val/g" infile.sql > outfile.sql
jon@jontest:~$ cat infile.sql
aaaaa
bbbbb?
?ccccc
dd?ddd
e?ee?ee
jon@jontest:~$ cat outfile.sql
aaaaa
bbbbb34523
34523ccccc
dd34523ddd
e34523ee34523ee
```

The `g` at the end of the s expression given to sed means *global* and will ensure you replace all occurrences of `?` for each line sed performs the replace on.

One-lined with your params:

```
var=`cat done.txt`; sed "s/\?/$var/g" CreateView.sql > CreateViewFinal.sql
```